# Zuora. Getting payment associated with payment refund

Tags: zuora, zuora-soap

How i can get `PaymentId` associated with a refund using API?

for example, i can get this using builtin callback `Payment Refund Processed`
[image]

But i can't found a way for getting `PaymentId` using a similar custom callback or REST\SOAP API.

Do you have any idea how i can get `paymentId` by `RefundId` without "Invoice Settlement feature"?

Answer (score -1):

Try using refund parts API call as shown below.
../v1/refunds/{refundId}/parts